# On Prem Django app login with Azure AD Credentials

Tags: python, django, azure, django-admin, django-authentication

I have a usecase, we have a Django application running in onprem and it has admin login page, we have few users in Azure AD, we dont have any onprem AD, i want users to be authenticate with Azure AD,

Can someone guide me how can this be achieved.

Comment: I found this one, trying not sure how it goes - 
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/msid-django-web-app-sign-in/1-introduction)